# return array from perl to bash

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to get back an array from perl to bash.

My perl scrip has an array and then I use `return(@arr)`

from my bash script I use

```
VAR = `perl....
```

when I echo VAR 
I get the aray as 1 long string with all the array vars connected with no spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the shell (and in Perl), backticks (``` `` ```) capture the output of a command. However, Perl's [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) is normally for returning variables from subroutines - it does not produce output, so you probably want [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) instead. Also, in `bash`, [array variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) are declared with parentheses. So this works for me:

```
$ ARRAY=(`perl -wMstrict -le 'my @array = qw/foo bar baz/; print "@array"'`); \
    echo "<${ARRAY[*]}> 0=${ARRAY[0]} 1=${ARRAY[1]} 2=${ARRAY[2]}"
<foo bar baz> 0=foo 1=bar 2=baz
```

In Perl, interpolating an array into a string (like `"@array"`) will join the array with the special variable [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$") in between elements; that variable defaults to a single space. If you simply `print @array`, then the array elements will be joined by the variable [`$,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$,), which is `undef` by default, meaning no space between the elements. This probably explains the behavior you mentioned (*"the array vars connected with no spaces"*).

Note that the above will **not** work the way you expect if the elements of the array contain whitespace, because `bash` will split them into separate array elements. If your array does contain whitespace, then please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample data so we can perhaps make an alternative suggestion of how to return that back to `bash`. For example:

```bash
( # subshell so IFS is only affected locally
    IFS=$'\n'
    ARRAY=(`perl -wMstrict -e 'my @array = ("foo","bar","quz baz"); print join "\n", @array'`)
    echo "0=<${ARRAY[0]}> 1=<${ARRAY[1]}> 2=<${ARRAY[2]}>"
)
```

Outputs: `0=<foo> 1=<bar> 2=<quz baz>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using Bash [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting), it will split the string on white space into the new array `array`:

```
array_str=$(perl -E '@a = 1..5; say "@a"')
array=( $array_str )

for item in ${array[@]} ; do
    echo ": $item"
done
```

**Output**:

```
: 1
: 2
: 3
: 4
: 5
```